# Is this loginRequired(f)() the way to handle login required functions in dart?

Tags: dart, flutter

I am new to Dart programming. I am trying to figure out what is the proper way (what everyone will do) to handle/guard those functions which are login required. The following is my first trial:

`$ vim login_sample.dart:`

```dart
var isLoggedIn;

class LoginRequiredException implements Exception {
  String cause;
  LoginRequiredException(this.cause);
}

Function loginRequired(Function f) {
  if (!isLoggedIn) {
    throw new LoginRequiredException("Login is reuiqred.");
  }
  return f;
}

void secretPrint() {
  print("This is a secret");
}

void main(List<String> args) {
  if (args.length != 1) return null;
  isLoggedIn = (args[0] == '1') ? true : false;
  try {
    loginRequired(secretPrint)();
  } on LoginRequiredException {
    print("Login is required!");
  }
}
```

then, run it with `$ dart login_sample.dart 1` and `$ dart login_sample.dart 2`.

I am wondering if this is the recommended way to guard login required functions or not.

Thank you very much for your help.

**Edited:**

My question is more about general programming skills in `Dart` than how to use a plugin. In python, I just need to add `@login_required` decorator in the front of the function to protect it. I am wondering if this decorator function way is recommended in dart or not.

PS: All firebase/google/twitter/facebook etc... are blocked in my country.

Answer (score 1):

I like the functional approach. I'd only avoid using globals, you can wrap it in a `Context` so you can mock then for tests and use `Future`s as Monads: https://dartpad.dartlang.org/ac24a5659b893e8614f3c29a8006a6cc

Answer (score 1):

Passing the function is not buying much value. In a typical larger Dart project using a framework there will be some way to guard at a higher level than a function - such as an entire page or component/widget.

If you do want to guard at a per-function level you first need to decide with it should be the *function* or the *call site* that decides what needs to be guarded. In your example it is the *call site* making the decision. After that decision you can implement a `throwIfNotAuthenticated` and add a call at either the definition or call site.

```
void throwIfNotAuthenticated() {
  if (!userIsAuthenticated) {
    throw new LoginRequiredException();
  }
}

// Function decides authentication is required:
void secretPrint() {
  throwIfNotAuthenticated();
  print('This is a secret');
}

// Call site decides authentication is required:
void main() {
  // do stuff...
  throwIfNotAuthenticated();
  anotherSecreteMethod();
}
```